# Need a good IDE for CodeIgniter

Tags: ide, codeigniter

I am using NANO editor, and moving back and forth between MVC is really painful.

i tried notepad++ but still i have to click back and forth b/t MVC

is there something like Mac's TextMate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.

http://www.e-texteditor.com/

It's nearly identical to TextMate and even uses the same plugins.

Comment: OMG look this cute car insurance japanese website!

Comment: Now seriously ^^ http://e-texteditor.en.softonic.com/

Answer (score 5):

I have been using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) for PHP and found it really useful with CodeIgniter.

[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/) is another good ide.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use Eclipse for PHP, in Sympfony and Zend Framework projects, using MVC on both. Netbeans should be good too.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR1/eclipse-php-galileo-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz